# how to import other component on button click vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i want to show other component when i click a button and of course i want to send params too, how i can do it?

im only know basic usage import in vue, here what i create.

here my template parent

```
<template>
    <div class="detail-project">
      <selectpersons></selectpersons>
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="selectPerson(param1, param2)"></button>
</template>
```

and this my script

```
import selectpersons from './ActionDetailProject/selectPerson.vue';
    export default {
    components: {
        selectpersons
    },
    methods: {
     selectPerson(param1, param2){
        //not sure what i have to write here...
     },
    }
```

with this code te component is showing without i click the button, i want to show the component `selectpersons` when i click the button

Answer (score 0):

You want the component *selectpersons* to be invisible untill someone click a button?
Then do something like this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="detail-project">
      <selectpersons v-show="visible"></selectpersons>
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="selectPerson(param1, param2)"></button>
</template>
```

```
export default {
    data: {
        visible: false,
    },
    components: {
        selectpersons
    },
    methods: {
     selectPerson(param1, param2){
         this.visible = true
     },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-show` or `v-if` for this component depending on your need. `v-show` adds a css property `display: none;` and keeps the component in the DOM but it is hidden. `v-if` does not render and you won't find it in the DOM until you click on the button.

```
<selectpersons v-show="showComponent"></selectpersons>
<selectpersons v-if="showComponent"></selectpersons>

<button v-on:click="selectPerson(param1, param2)"></button>

import selectpersons from './ActionDetailProject/selectPerson.vue';
  export default {
  components: {
    selectpersons
  },
  data: {
    showComponent: false,
  },
  methods: {
   selectPerson(param1, param2){
    this.showComponent = true
   },
 }
```

to learn more about conditional rendering https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html